# How to deal with exponent overflow of 64float precision in python?

Tags: python, numpy

I am a newbie in python sorry for the simple question.

In the following code, I want to calculate the exponent and then take the log.

`Y=numpy.log(1+numpy.exp(1000))`

The problem is that when I take the exponent of 710 or larger numbers the numpy.exp() function returns 'inf' even if I print it with 64float it prints 'inf'.

any help regarding the problem will be appreciated.

Comment: for an `n` that big, `numpy.log(1+numpy.exp(1000))`  will just be `n`. What is the precision you need?

Comment: checkout float absorption. `1+numpy.exp(100)` is already equal to `numpy.exp(100)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the function `np.logaddexp()` to do such operations. It computes `logaddexp(x1, x2) == log(exp(x1) + exp(x2))` without explicitly computing the intermediate `exp()` values. This avoids the overflow. Since `exp(0.0) == 1`, you would compute `np.logaddexp(0.0, 1000.0)` and get the result of `1000.0`, as expected.

Comment: Awesome, simple answer. Thank you, Robert

Answer (score 2):

Use the decimal library:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.exp(1000)
inf
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> x = Decimal(1000)
>>> np.exp(x)
Decimal('1.970071114017046993888879352E+434')
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this out:

```
>>> x = numpy.exp(100)
>>> y = x+1
>>> y==x
True
```

so even with `100` (which computes all right), adding 1 (or even a very big number), the lowest value is absorbed and has absolutely no effect in the addition. Both values are strictly equal.

Playing with `sys.float_info.epsilon` I tested that:

```
>>> numpy.log(1e20+numpy.exp(100))==numpy.log(numpy.exp(100))
True
>>> numpy.log(1e30+numpy.exp(100))==numpy.log(numpy.exp(100))
False
```

so even a value like `1e20` is absorbed by `exp(100)` ...

So you would get exactly `1000.0` as your result even if it worked.